# How to create multiple subdirectories?

Tags: python

I want to be able to create 5 sub-directories of a folder using a loop in python. They should all have the name `subdir_n` where `n` is a number from 1 through 5. I tried this using a `for` loop, but I can't seem to get the naming right. Here is what I am using.

```
import os

def createSubDirectories():
    for i in range(1,6):
        os.mkdir('/home/student/lab3/subdir_{i}')

createSubDirectories()
```

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting you seem to want to use is `f-string`, and you need to prefix the string by an `f`

```
f'/home/student/lab3/subdir_{i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt looks good except for the way you are generating the subdirectory names:

Try this instead:

```
os.mkdir('/home/student/lab3/subdir_{}'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
os.mkdir( f'/home/student/lab3/subdir_{i}' )
```